# How can I convert a dict to a unicode JSON string?

Tags: python, json

This doesn't appear to be possible to me using the standard library `json` module. When using `json.dumps` it will automatically escape all non-ASCII characters then encode the string to ASCII. I can specify that it not escape non-ASCII characters, but then it crashes when it tries to convert the output to ASCII.

The problem is - **I don't want ASCII!** I just want my JSON string back as a *unicode* (or *UTF-8*) string. Are there any convenient ways to do that?

Here's an example to demonstrate what I **want**:

```
d = {'navn': 'Åge', 'stilling': 'Lærling'}
json.dumps(d, output_encoding='utf8')
# => '{"stilling": "Lærling", "navn": "Åge"}'
```

But of course, there is no such option as *output_encoding*, so here's the actual output:

```
d = {'navn': 'Åge', 'stilling': 'Lærling'}
json.dumps(d)
# => '{"stilling": "L\\u00e6rling", "navn": "\\u00c5ge"}'
```

So to summarize - I want to convert a Python dict to an ***UTF-8 JSON string*** without any escapes. How can I do that?

---

I'll accept solutions like:

- Hacks (pre- and post processing input to `dumps` to achieve the desired effect)
- Subclassing the [JSONEncoder](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) (I have no idea how it works and the documentation isn't very helpful)
- Third party libraries available on PyPi

Comment: Actually json.dumps does come with a "encoding" parameter, which defaults to utf-8.  Try in a python console typing help(json.dumps)

Comment: @JamesHurford: Yes I know, that's a parameter to tell `json` which encoding the ***input*** strings in the dict have. It has nothing to do with the output, and I need the ***output*** string to be UTF-8

Comment: Have a look at http://bit.ly/unipain

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Requirements

- Make sure your python files are encoded in UTF-8. Or else your non-ascii characters will become question marks, `?`. Notepad++ has excellent encoding options for this.
- Make sure that you have the appropriate fonts included. If you want to display Japanese characters then you need to install Japanese fonts.
- Make sure that your IDE supports displaying unicode characters.
  Otherwise you might get an `UnicodeEncodeError` error thrown.

Example:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 22-23: character maps to <undefined>
```

PyScripter works for me. It's included with "Portable Python" at http://portablepython.com/wiki/PortablePython3.2.1.1

- Make sure you're using Python 3+, since this version offers better unicode support.

## Problem

json.dumps() escapes unicode characters.

## Solution

Read the update at the bottom. Or...

Replace each escaped characters with the parsed unicode character.

I created a simple lambda function called `getStringWithDecodedUnicode` that does just that.

```
import re   
getStringWithDecodedUnicode = lambda str : re.sub( '\\\\u([\da-f]{4})', (lambda x : chr( int( x.group(1), 16 ) )), str )
```

Here's `getStringWithDecodedUnicode` as a regular function.

```
def getStringWithDecodedUnicode( value ):
    findUnicodeRE = re.compile( '\\\\u([\da-f]{4})' )
    def getParsedUnicode(x):
        return chr( int( x.group(1), 16 ) )

    return  findUnicodeRE.sub(getParsedUnicode, str( value ) )
```

## Example

### testJSONWithUnicode.py (Using PyScripter as the IDE)

```
import re
import json
getStringWithDecodedUnicode = lambda str : re.sub( '\\\\u([\da-f]{4})', (lambda x : chr( int( x.group(1), 16 ) )), str )

data = {"Japan":"日本"}
jsonString = json.dumps( data )
print( "json.dumps({0}) = {1}".format( data, jsonString ) )
jsonString = getStringWithDecodedUnicode( jsonString )
print( "Decoded Unicode: %s" % jsonString )
```

### Output

```
json.dumps({'Japan': '日本'}) = {"Japan": "\u65e5\u672c"}
Decoded Unicode: {"Japan": "日本"}
```

## Update

Or... just pass `ensure_ascii=False` as an option for json.dumps.

Note: You need to meet the requirements that I outlined at the beginning or else this isn't going to work.

```
import json
data = {'navn': 'Åge', 'stilling': 'Lærling'}
result = json.dumps(d, ensure_ascii=False)
print( result ) # prints '{"stilling": "Lærling", "navn": "Åge"}'
```

Comment: Exactly the same conclusion I came to.  The only niggle I have is that simplejson is now named json, in 2.7 onwards.  So you would go import json not import simplejson as json

Comment: I don't understand. In my question I say that **I don't want ASCII**, yet your conclusion shows only ASCII output :P The entire point of my question was to get a unicode JSON string, yours are *all* ASCII

Comment: This doesn't work - try to run `json.dumps({"Japan":"日本"}, ensure_ascii=False)`. Additionally, I already stated in my question that `ensure_ascii` doesn't change the output encoding - it still tries to encode using ASCII, just without escaping non-ASCII characters first

Comment: +1 Yeah this works, voted you up now. If I'm outputting a JSON string with millions of characters this is still a pretty wasteful solution though. I'm keeping this question open for other answers

Comment: @Codemonkey Oh...it seems that passing the option 'ensure_ascii=False' worked the whole time as long as you meet the requirements.

Comment: `json.dumps("ä", ensure_ascii=False)` produces  `"Ã¤"`. So the updated answer is wrong.

Comment: Thanks! Very good decision!

Answer (score 6):

`encode_ascii=False` is the best solution IMHO.

If you are using Python2.7, here is example python file :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# example.py
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from json import dumps as json_dumps
d = {'navn': 'Åge', 'stilling': 'Lærling'}
print json_dumps(d, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: The specs are incorrect. They mention "If ensure_ascii is True (the default), the output is guaranteed to have all incoming non-ASCII characters escaped. If ensure_ascii is False, these characters will be output as-is."

But `json.dumps(d, ensure_ascii=False)` is **always** returns `unicode`-typed string.

Comment: @avesus The spec is correct. It returns `unicode` because I used `from __future__ import unicode_literals`

Comment: In case of me, I used True option to use the converted string for socket.send

message_string = json_dumps(aMessageDic, ensure_ascii=True).encode('utf-8')
            
socket.send(message_string)

Answer (score 0):

If on Python3.7 this is what worked for me

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
print json.dumps(m,ensure_ascii=False)
```

Make sure `from __future__ import unicode_literals` is the first line to be imported.