# Getting Django object "is not JSON serializable"

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

I have a webservice that reads a JSON object and it was giving me unicodeEncodeError exception. After googling a little bit, I saw [How can I convert a dict to a unicode JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699407/how-can-i-convert-a-dict-to-a-unicode-json-string)

(I followed other questions that were related to unicodeEncodeError but I was still getting AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'content')

I did what was mentioned in that particular question and now I am getting **..... is not JSON serializable**

Can anyone tell me what do I have to do now?

Following is my code:

```
def someMethod()
    some_data = request.data
    json_string1 = json.dumps(some_data)           #GETTING ERROR ON THIS LINE
    json_string2 = get_string(json_string1)
    archive = call.send_json(json_string2)


def get_string(value):
    find_unicode = re.compile('\\\\u([\da-f]{4})')

    def get_parsed_unicode(x):
        return chr(int(x.group(1), 16))
    return find_unicode.sub(get_parsed_unicode, str(value))
```

Thanks for the help !!

Comment: What does request.data contain? `print request.data` and `print type(request.data)`

Comment: @laffuste: 'print request.data' returns the JSON that is passed as a String in the Web service and 'print type(request.data) returns '<type 'dict'>'

Answer (score 0):

When you're passing the object to the method, use `foo.serealize(true)`. Include JQUERY to use this.